# What to do with the <Empty Div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags --> <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <title>Sean Kim</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/grids-responsive-old-ie-min.css">
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/grids-responsive-min.css">
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="custom-menu-wrapper">
    <div class="pure-menu custom-menu custom-menu-top">
      <a href="#" class="pure-menu-heading custom-menu-brand">Sean Kim</a>
      <a href="#" class="custom-menu-toggle" id="toggle"><s class="bar"></s><s class="bar"></s></a>
    </div>
    <div class="me" id="home">
      <br><br><br>
      <h1 class="name">SEAN KIM</h1>
      <hr>
      <h6 class="intro">14 year-old programmer/student at Bergen County Academies</h6>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <img src="images/nyc.jpg" class="img-responsive nyc">
    </div>
    <div id="about">
      <h2 class="about-text">About Me</h2>
      <img src="images/golf.png" align="left"class="propic">
      <p class="info">My name is Sean Kim and I'm a freshman at 
        <a href="http://bcts.bergen.org/index.php/bergen-county-academies" class="bca">
          Bergen County Academies
        </a> in the Academy of Technology and Computer Science (ATCS).
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="skills">
      <h2 class="skills-text">Skills</h2>
      <div class="pure-g">
        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-4 html5">
          <img src="images/logos/html5.png" alt="HTML 5" width="106" height="150">
          <p class="languages">HTML 5</p>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-4 css3">
          <img src="images/logos/css.png" alt="CSS3" width="106" height="150">
          <p class="languages">CSS3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-4 python">
          <img src="images/logos/python.png" alt="PYTHON" width="150" height="150">
          <p class="languages">PYTHON</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-container" id="contact">
      <h2 class="contact-text">Contact Me</h2>
      <div class="pure-g contact">
        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-4 Facebook">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/seankim327" target="_blank" class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-5x"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-4 Instagram">
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/seankim.co.kr" target="_blank" class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-5x"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-4 Twitter">
          <a href="https:/www.twitter.com/sean_d_kim" target="_blank" class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-5x"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-4 GitHub">
          <a href="https://github.com/seankim327" target="_blank" class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-github-square fa-5x"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script>
        function sendMail(email, subject, content) {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json',
            data: {
              'key': 'goYVUvLoJH3ICbEMgIA-ow',
              'message': {
                'from_email': email,
                'to': [
                    {
                      'email': 'seandyk@gmail.com',
                      'name': 'Sean Kim',
                      'type': 'to'
                    }
                  ],
                'autotext': 'true',
                'subject': subject,
                'html': content
              }
            }
           }).done(function(response) {
            if (response[0].status == "rejected") {
              document.getElementById("<div id="about"></div>").innerHTML = "Please enter valid fields";
            } else {
              document.getElementById("<div id="skills"></div>").innerHTML = "Sent!";
            }
         });
        }
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I asked my friend who's good with JavaScript to write me code that can send emails, so he used the Mandrill API and wrote me one. But he told me to replace the `<Empty Div>` with "empty `div`s" or I need a `span` to output to. I have no idea what that means. Can someone help?

Comment: can you provide HTML code?

Comment: You need to place a div with an id in your html like `<div id="mymailresult"></div>` then place the id of that div in place of `Empty Div`

Comment: and duly note `id`s will not contain space as your friend have written **Empty Div** it should have been `EmptyDiv` or `Empty_Div` something like that..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao `<Empty Div>` was not supposed to be an ID but was supposed to be _replaced_ by an ID.

Comment: I know @Xufox but since he is a beginner that was a suggestion..

Answer (score 2):

An Empty div is one that had both an open and close but has no contents or other elements as contents between that open and close.

The Div in question that your friend was referring to in the code is:

```
<div class="element"></div>
```

It is located just under the line that has the text

```
14 year-old programmer/student at Bergen County Academies
```

Answer (score 0):

He's saying that in your html, you need to create a `div` tag. He's basically saying "hey, my code is going to do something and you need to create a `div` tag in your html page so that my code can put it into it. Once you create this `div` tag, go to the code I gave you and replace the `<Empty Div>` with whatever you labled the `id` as.

`<div id="myDiv"></div>`

Then, in the code that your friend gave you, replace `<Empty Div>` with the `id attribute` (`myDiv`)

Comment: do I create the div anywhere in my html code? (i don't know much cus i've only been programming for about a year)

Comment: If you paste your html code, we could certainly answer that for you. I would start by adding it within the `<body>`. You can always hit F12 to bring up the developer tools and debug.

Answer (score 0):

In short use an `id` attribute, say, "email-status", on an element in your HTML `body` where you want the status update to appear. Reference it using `document.getElementById('email-status')`.

Here is a more detailed explanation with links for more information.

Both [`div`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp), which is a [block](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) element (which by default appears separated by newlines from surrounding text), or a [`span`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp), which is an [inline](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) element, are HTML tags that are regularly referenced and manipulated in Javascript.

When you want to replace the content of a *specific* element you typically create a selector using an [`id`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) attribute.  The `id` value cannot have spaces and should be unique among all `id` values in the document.

For example, an HTML `div` with an `id` of "mail-response" would simply be written:

```
<div id="mail-status"></div>
```

This `div` above would be placed in the HTML document `body` where you want your status message to appear.

While you could use a `class` attribute as your selector as another reply suggested, in this case it is not ideal.  The `class` attribute is not necessarily unique as it was initially intended to apply CSS formatting to one or more elements.  Generally speaking there may be other times when you want to use Javascript to select all tags with a particular class.  In your particular case, you want to target one particular location so an `id` is more appropriate.

To select a `div` based on its `id` you can use `document.getElementById` like you did, but it simply takes a parameter of the `id` value you want to select.

```
document.getElementById("mail-response").innerHTML = "Entry is <b>invalid</b>";
```

In your example, the `done` function reads:

```
function(response) {
    if (response[0].status == "rejected") {
        document.getElementById("<div id="about"></div>").innerHTML = "Please enter valid fields";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("<div id="skills"></div>").innerHTML = "Sent!";
    }
}
```

Note that there are two problems here.  First is that the `getElementById` simple takes an `id` value as its parameter not an HTML snippet.  Second, is that you had unescaped double quotes within a double-quoted string.

A minimal correction would be to change the block to reference the existing `value` and `skills` `div`s directly.

```
function(response) {
    if (response[0].status == "rejected") {
        document.getElementById("about").innerHTML = "Please enter valid fields";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("skills").innerHTML = "Sent!";
    }
}
```

Note however, that the `about` and `skills` element currently contain content.  Replacing the innerHTML will remove the content currently in those elements.  Based on your other comments it sounds like rather than replacing the existing blocks you would prefer to insert the status update into an initially empty element that has been set aside for the status update.

Finally, I would suggest that if you in fact posted your actual mandrill API key, that you change it immediately.